# Implementing Clicklistners on navigation menu

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I created an android navigation activity from an android studio. Now in that activity how should I implement the click listener on the menu of the navigation drawer? Like on click of menu item how can I do some task 
Activity is :
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

```
private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow,
            R.id.nav_tools, R.id.nav_share, R.id.nav_send)
            .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
            || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

    switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
            case R.id.nav_home:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Home", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: you should use onNavigationItemSelected and differentiate menu items by their ids in menu.xml 
and perform task what you want

Answer (score 1):

use this as example.

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
     case R.id.nav_home:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Home", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
     case R.id.nav_otherId:
        //your action
        Toast.makeText(this, "Gallery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
     case R.id.nav_otherId2:
        //your action
        Toast.makeText(this, "Next", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;


}
return true;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

3.5 upgrade is causing XML to be improperly reordered, and it's moving the  to above (and therefore, behind) the main content in the . You'll need to move the  to after the  (or whatever else you might have for the main content). And boom you are good to go

and in java

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(new NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDestinationChanged(@NonNull NavController controller, @NonNull
                    NavDestination destination, @Nullable Bundle arguments) {
                if (destination.getId() == R.id.nav_home) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "home", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                if (destination.getId() == R.id.nav_gallery) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "nav_gallery", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                if (destination.getId() == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "nav_slideshow", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                if (destination.getId() == R.id.nav_tools) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "nav_tools", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                if (destination.getId() == R.id.nav_share) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "nav_share", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                if (destination.getId() == R.id.nav_send) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "nav_send", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're looking for:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if(id == R.id.hello){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenu.this, HelloActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```